# Better service manager utility for Windows?

Tags: windows, services, windows-services

The default service manager utility in Windows is kind of inconvenient.
Is there any (possibly free) utility that can...

1. Change startup settings of multiple services at once (using checkboxes or something)
2. Show more helpful description using its own knowledge base. What the service really does, when the service is needed, etc.
3. Export/Import startup settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i can save you:))

The avg Pc tuneUp is what you need exactly. It controls services of all Programs you installed. You can select which to disable and it will be reEnabled when you run the program and after you close it avg will disable it automatically. It means you only have 1 service running which is avg pc tune up.
For Windows services you have to do it manually because its system services.
But programs like chrome Firefox, Microsoft office and ... Will be disabled automatically.
You can find this function in the avg settings.

Answer (score 1):

This program is from Microsoft. It may be helpful for making running services less cryptic:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

CC cleaner has check boxes for startup programs:

http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download

Answer (score 0):

## Try ServiWin

NirSoft has [`ServiWin`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html).

It can display both drivers and services. It starts up in "Drivers List" mode. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> to switch to "Services List" mode.

It can only do some of what you want:

> 1. Change startup settings of multiple services at once (using checkboxes or something)

Yes. Shift-click several services to select and then right-click.

> 2. Show more helpful description using its own knowledge base. What the service really does, when the service is needed, etc.

No. And since you can run anything as a service, I don't think an exhaustive list is even possible. But it does list the built in Windows description. And it has a right-click shortcut to search for the service name on Google.

> 3. Export/Import startup settings.

Export yes. Import no.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using NSSM and is quite alright for managing services but it's all command line
https://nssm.cc/download

And there's this little tool I just found which looks better than NSSM
https://sysprogs.com/legacy/tools/srvman/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172800)